# PHP Defining array variable within logical operator

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, if-statement

I'm trying to define a point in an array within a logical operator. Is this possible?

e.g.

```
$a = $deg[0];
$b = $deg[1];
$c = $deg[2];
$d = $deg[3];
$e = $deg[4];

if ($c == False){
$array['$a']['$b'][0][1] = $value;


} else {

if ($d == False){
$array['$a']['$b']['$c'][0][1] = $value;


} else {

if ($e == False){
$array['$a']['$b']['$c']['$d'][0][1] = $value;
}
```

Is there a reason the array variable is not being defined?

Comment: if none of the variables == false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with removing ' single quotes

```
$array[$a][$b][0][1] = $value;
```

and it not wise to use key word like `array` as variable name

Comment: yep, single quotes are not helping

Comment: ahhh! lol the basics ;) Yeh I changed array name for examples. But thanks that works a treat!!